# Nvidia crash linux mint 16

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I'm trying to install nvidia drivers but when I install it and reboot I'm getting popup with information about crash system. And I have excluded Cinnamon.

I'm doing it by those commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Result of cinnamon --replace:

```
$ cinnamon --replace
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
libEGL warning: GLX/DRI2 is not supported
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

(cinnamon:2928): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cinnamon:2928): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: The OpenGL version could not be determined
Window manager error: Unable to initialize Clutter.
```

Thanks for all tips.

Edit:
When I was installing nvidia driver using apt-get I had this info:

```
(....)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.3-031303-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_sdma.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_rlc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_mc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_mec.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_ce.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_me.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/HAWAII_pfp.bin for module radeon
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

nVidia binary drivers have been blacklisted by the kernel people for a *long* time now, as they have been shown time and again to be responsible for all sorts of misbehaviour. Chuck them, the open source nouveau drivers have advanced enormously.